# Beith Habechira Vs. Beit Hamikdash

Tags: tefilla, words, beis-hamikdash

In the Haggadah, in Dayeinu we say the final lines about Hashem's building for us (itself a curious idea) the temple. But different texts have different wording.

One haggadah reads "vlo vana lanu et beit habechirah" (visible [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=TrkA5rJkAv8C&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=et%20beit%20habechirah&source=bl&ots=2HhB2BBrqI&sig=SiIsf2glN_sbf5Pv9E0iz-VRrTE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKrP6PjKLTAhWM34MKHdvcDj8Q6AEIQDAE#v=onepage&q=et%20beit%20habechirah&f=false)) while [others](https://www.haggadot.com/clip/dayenu-english-hebrew-and-transliteration) read "et beit hamikdash."

I know that in musaf davening for the 3 regalim (using my Artscroll), the phrase "la'asot chovoteinu b'veit bechiratecha" appears and Yerushalayim in general is called "beit mikdashecha" (the home of your mikdash) whereas in musaf for Rosh Chodesh, the phrase is "uva'avodat beit hamikdash nismach" (and then later the same reference to Jerusalem).

Is there a functional difference between referring to a beit habechira and a beit hamikdash that would explain any particular textual choice? Did one develop as a recognized name earlier or are they pointing to different specific things?

Comment: See Reshimot Shiurim of the Rav to Berakhot 62b.

Comment: 'Beit HaMikdash' and 'Beit HaBehira' are both used in Tannaic literature. The latter appearing just a few times in the Mishna and Tosefta, and the former appearing many times in those works.

Comment: The version of the Shibbolei HaLeket actually seems to have listed the Beit HaMikdash and Beit HaBehira separately. He explains that the former refers to the ohel mo'ed in nov, givon and Shiloh, while the latter refers to the first Temple: 
 אם הכניסנו לארץ ישראל ולא בנה לנו את בית המקדש הרי זו חיבה גדולה ודי לנו ואחרי שכפל גם זאת להכניסנו לארץ ישראל ולבנות לנו את בית המקדש זהו אוהל מועד שנתיישב בנוב וגבעון ושילה...ולא בנה לנו את בית הבחירה זה בית המקדש שבנה שלמה הוא הנקרא...ובית הבחירה על שם אל המקום אשר יבחר ה' שאין עוד אחריה היתר לבמות היתה חיבה גדולה ודי לנו. כ"ש שעשה עמנו כל אלה

Comment: That may not count as answer since the question was about the choice of one, whereas his text had both.